# Layers not lining up

Tags: qgis, coordinates

I have a layer from one source that was originally in one coordinate system and am attempting to use it with map layers from Google and Open Maps.  I have set the project properties, the map layer and the shapefile all to EPSG 42105 - WGS84.

Is there some other setting or something?

The shapefile is in North America and when I zoom to the layer I see it in an ocean somewhere.    It is still blue water as I zoom to the where I can no longer see the shapefile.

Comment: 42105 isn't an EPSG well-known ID. spatialreference.org brings up several Idaho State Plane definitions that have Esri WKIDs, but none directly use 42105 nor WGS84. Please edit your question with the extent of the layer. That will help us figure out what its coordinate reference system really is.

Comment: And what coordinates does QGIS think it is displaying? As well as a CRS error (cf. @mkennedy's reply) it could be a simple problem light a sign on a hemisphere, or a scale/units issue. (okay both of those are technically CRS issues but your shapefile might not be what you think it is)

Comment: In other.extra `CubeWerx-defined extended codes  (42100--42199)`, I have `# WGS84 / Merc NorthAm
<42105> +proj=merc +lat_ts=0 +lon_0=-96 +k=1.000000 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs  no_defs <>`

Comment: If your data is showing up in an ocean, it's probably in decimal degrees AKA a geographic coordinate reference system like WGS84.

Comment: Thanks for the replies and sorry for the late response from me.  I've been busy with other things. Here is the info on the extents, etc of the layer and of Google Maps.  I've never done much with coordinate systems before so bear with me.